# Ignore hidden rows after filter in for each

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on VBA Excel, and,
I Need to filter table, then make a loop in filtered values.
But i tryed:

```vba
With Sheets("plan8")
        .Activate
        totalAdhoc = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count
        With .Range("A2:S" & totalAdhoc + 1)
            .CurrentRegion.Select
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=batch, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            For Each selectedV In Selection
                r = selectedV
            Next
        End With
    End With
```

In this way, my loop pass over each cell, in rows and columns.
If i use Range, it pass over hidden cells, then filter isn't efective.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | a | 1 | x |
| xx | s | 2 | x |
| xx | f | 3 | x |

I Filtered this table for Column "A", then i need compare my variable to column "B", then change value of Column "D".

The For in entire table is very slow.

Comment: You don't need to activate anything. You can set the *table* range with `Set srg = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion`. If `S` is not the last column you can append `.Columns("A:S")`. You can set the *data* range with `Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)`. What is `batch`? Is it a string or an array? After the AutoFitler, you can set the range with e.g. `Set vrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and loop through it's areas and rows. Depending on the amount of your data, this might take forever. Using arrays might be preferable. Please do clarify your *Columns A, B, D* business.

Comment: i put activate, because my code start in other sheet, and i want to see what happens. `batch` is string that contains the parameter from the other sheet.
And `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` Resolved all my problems

Answer (score 2):

Without trying to figure out exactly what you're doing, here is an example of using a loop through a range and checking if row is hidden/filtered or not:

```
Sub loopSomeRows()

Dim aCell As Range, LoopRange As Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    Set LoopRange = ws.Range("B:B") ' sample
    
    For Each aCell In Intersect(LoopRange, ws.UsedRange).Cells
        If aCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            'this row is hidden so it would be ignored.
            
        Else
            'this row is visible, so write code for what you want to happen
           Debug.Print "Visible " & aCell.Value
            
        End If
    Next aCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I Need to make a loop only in rows that are visible after filter, and not check if it's visible or not.
I Solved it with comment in question, adding: `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` . After Range

Comment: Oh, I should have known better. I only answered the exact language in the title of your question, "*Ignore hidden rows after filter in for each*". Glad it works...